# Loop to ensure inputbox entry is eight characters long and numeric

Tags: excel, vba

In one of my weekly files I'm having an issue with a loop that would provide the date portion of the file name.

The file could be produced any day in the week or the first couple days the week after it relates to depending on when the source data is ready but must be prefixed with a date in yyyymmdd format of the last date it contains data on.

The easiest way to do this is to set this via an inputbox at the start of the macro which can then be called upon later when saving the component reports into their folders.

My issue is the user could put anything into the inputbox (which I think needs to be formatted as string for other elements as I don't understand VBA enough to know how calling a number variable into my save as name would work).

I want to add a loop that says if it is 8 characters long and a numeric continue else re-enter date.

```vb
Dim svdate As String
Sub inpt()
Do
    svdate = InputBox("date")
    If Len(svdate) = 8 And IsNumeric(svdate) Then
        MsgBox svdate
    Else
        MsgBox ("the value should be a number in format yyyymmdd please try inputting the date again")
    End If
Loop Until True
```

I have been testing the above code in a separate sub hence the msgbox on the if true section which would be replaced with the rest of the subs that would be run once the date is entered correctly.

I have defined the svdate variable as a module level item as it is called upon in many other stages within the wider macro which all work. I just want the assurance that a user could only enter an appropriate date before combining the code.

As the code stands it'll ask me to input the date into the box and then show one of the 2 msgbox once but if false won't return to the inputbox stage.

Comment: Question: why do you think the loop should run again? Currently it loops until true = true. ... You need a variable that is true when svdate is ok and that is false if not. Then your `loop until` check has to evaluate this variable. BTW @ChristoferWeber: It is ok to have a colon after else because it then acts like two commands in one line.

Comment: thanks edited this as it was just a copy dump from my vba editor never added the colon myself so not sure why it was there still not looping though

Comment: hi ike haven't i put in a loop that says is the answer to the if stement true if yes end loop if not go back untilto the start of the loop to make it true (the kloop until true line at the end of the code). 

if not how do I do this as I am trying to ensure that the user gets the error message explaining why the input box needs refilling and then pops up again until a valid value is entered

Comment: Just like the `If` is followed by a statement that returns true or false, `Loop until` does exactly the same. In your case the statement was `true`, which is like saying `If True Then` in the `If` equivalent, in that it will always return true. As Ike said, true = true.            
While you basically want                     
`Loop Until Len(svdate) = 8 And IsNumeric(svdate)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct looping:

```vb
Dim svdate As String
Sub inpt()
dim isOK as boolean
Do
    svdate = InputBox("date")
    If Len(svdate) = 8 And IsNumeric(svdate) Then
       isOK = true
      MsgBox svdate
    Else
       isOK = false
       MsgBox ("the value should be a number in format yyyymmdd please try inputting the date again")
    End If
Loop Until isOK = true
End Sub
```

In your code the `If`-loop is inside the `Do`-loop - therefore the `Do`-loop does not 'know' about the result of the check.

With my code `isOK` is set by the `If`-loop and the `do`-loop can evaluate it.

Comment: thanks for this just so i understand the logic of what went wrong and then with my code originally is whilst i had put in a loop statement there was nothing to tell vba that there was a true false value to loop through. is that correct? i'm guessing the Boolean portion just feeds a value that the loop function can understand is that right?

Comment: see my added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, you could as well use `Exit do`:

```
Dim svdate As String
Sub inpt()
Do
    svdate = InputBox("date")
    If Len(svdate) = 8 And IsNumeric(svdate) Then
        MsgBox svdate
        Exit do     'exit the loop
    Else
        MsgBox ("the value should be a number in format yyyymmdd please try inputting the date again")
    End If
Loop Until True
....
```

Comment: Its been a long time since I looked at this code as it behaves enough in my hands and I haven't needed to offload the work to other team members despite that why I created the macro. You are probably right that it should have the exit do portion in it. so next time I'm in the file I'll tidy that up so it looks more complete